# Grant access microsoft graph doesn't work

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I grant access for my app by this link for external account
http://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/Consent.aspx?ClientID=2a97adb7-8e24-4b30-9999-f7989af33a31&RequestedPermissions=DirectoryReaders

**Expected**:
 Receiving tenant id, and my app appears in the that external account http://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/ there

**Actually**:
I receiving tenant id, but my app doesn't appears in the that external account, so I can't authorize

**Code**:

```
def get_oauth_url(self, request):
    authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com'
    authorize_url = '{0}{1}'.format(authority, '/common/oauth2/authorize?{0}')
    params = {'client_id': (settings.OFFICE365_CLIENT_ID),
              'redirect_uri': request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('office365_oauth_return')),
              'response_type': 'code',
              'state': state,
              'resource': 'https://graph.microsoft.com',
              'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
              }

    return authorize_url.format(urlencode(params))
```

**Error:**

Issue
u'AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Authentication failed
Trace ID: 516d8605-4dc8-4dbe-9381-b22c49b2d9ee
Correlation ID: c8439084-4e3e-4301-8b10-141119be0c9a
Timestamp: 2016-08-24 15:57:19Z'

Comment: I strongly suggest: 1. describe the problem you're having clearly (what do you expect, what actually happens) 2. present a code example you need help with 3. format the question correctly. In current form, it will be most likely left unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Alexey - not sure where you got that consent link/URL above.  That's an old legacy URL that can only provide consent to Azure AD Graph API.  It would be interesting to understand what led you to using that URL.  I would recommend looking at the samples that we have for Microsoft Graph that are listed here https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/code-samples-and-sdks.  We have a sample there for Python - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python3-connect-rest-sample

Additionally for background on authorization/consent and acquiring tokens to Microsoft Graph, please see the following topic https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/auth_overview.

Hope this helps,